# Yii Submit Form in View page

Tags: php, forms, post, view, yii

I just started working with yii and I stumbled upon a problem.
I have a table called "users" and a table called "messages".
I basically want to have a page where I can view a user's details but also send him a message that would be saved in the message table.

I have a view called "user/view.php" which consists of:

```
<h1>View User #<?php echo $model->id; ?></h1>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    ),
)); ?>

<?php $message=new Message;
echo $this->renderPartial('_messagesend', array('model'=>$message)); ?>
```

the _messagesend form (created using gii) looks like:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'message-_messagesend-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    //for the sake of simplicity lets just insert the id's manually for now
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idFrom'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'idFrom'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'idFrom'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idTo'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'idTo'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'idTo'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'msg'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'msg'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'msg'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Send'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

I have a simple view in my UserController to display the details info:

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id)
        ));
    }
```

And now I want to figure out how i can add the controller to save the message. After gii creation I get a code which I tried to use and modify a little bit:

```
public function actionMessagesend()
    {
        $model=new Message;

        if(isset($_POST['Message']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Message'];
            if($model->save()){
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
                }
        }
        $this->render('_messagesend',array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

I tried to add this controller function in the UserController.php but it doesn't seem to work, I tried to add the same function to MessageController.php but it also doesn't seem to work. I tried to remove all the code and only add a redirect to show if the controllercode actually hits but it doesn't redirect (i tried it both in usercontroller and messagecontroller). So I have a feeling my code isn't reached. You guys have any idea what I'm missing here?

Maybe a little extra question: Is there a better suggestion to do what I want to do?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards,

WtFudgE

Comment: In this scenario I usually view the page source and see what the action URL is. Then I know what yii is trying to accomplish and work with it. Also note that in extreme circumstances you can chance the action URL when you initialize CActiveForm

Comment: Just a tip- Typically yii naming conventions will state that views which start with an underscore are intended to be partially rendered. It helps when you have 10s, 100s or 1000s of views to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message sending action isn't reached because by default the `CActiveForm` submits to the current page, so you will have to add the message processing to the `view` action, or you will need to set the `action` property for your `CActiveForm`.

Here is the link to the property documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#action-detail

So the form widget in the view should be something like:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'message-_messagesend-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'action' => array( '/message/messageSend' ), // change depending on your project
)); ?>
```

Comment: sweet, that did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by editing the submit button in the view page like this:

```
    <?php echo CHtml::button('Send', array('submit' => array('message/messageSend')));?>
```